# CSS - footer with the top image

Tags: css, html

I have my `html5` `footer` element on the bottom of my page and I want to set a background image on top of my `footer`.

I add the following CSS:

```
footer {
  background: #333333 url("footer_top.png") 50% 0 no-repeat;
  padding-top: 110px; # the image has 110px height
}
```

It works, however I get the problem of background-color (`#33333`) filling the space on the `right` and on the `left` of my centered background footer image, and what I want is to have the image absolutely on the `top` of the box with **no** footer background on either the left or the right.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please Create A JSFiddle File..Then it will be easy to help you..!!

Comment: a better solution is to get an image of right resolution, according to the screen, else you might be stretching the image or filling the left over space with some compatible color.

Comment: thats because you use it as a background-image. its kinda strechting it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A css background doesn't 'listen' to padding on the same element. the `<img>` tag does. If you want to position a background-image to the top you can use `background-position` for that.

Nonetheless i'm afraid you're trying something which will not really work out. My advice is to put a div or something above the footer which contains the image.(Since you want the image above the footer anyway)

```
<div class="background_thingie"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

And the CSS something like this:

```
.background_thingie {
    height: 110px;
    width 100%
    background: url(img) no-repeat top center;
}
```

Nonetheless; If you really want the background image in the footer pass it the same way as shown above in your footer(the `top center` part) Don't forget though: That if you don't repeat it, the width is going to run out one way or another which will leave the rest of the footer without a background image(If your footer is 1000px wide and the image is 500px wide for example)